# beamer color changes from slide to slide

Tags: beamer, color

I have a problem with colors that is rather weird. I wrote this presentation in beamer, and while I set all the color of the text with

```
\setbeamercolor{text1}{fg=SeaGreen!80!black}
```

and I use them with

```
\usebeamercolor[fg]{text1}
```

I realized that the color of the text changes from slide to slide, I mean something like 'green' instead of 'seagreen', regardless of the fact that I use always the same command to set the color. I don't manage yet to replicate this problem with a minimal example. Does anybody have any thoughts about what it could be?

Edit:

I realized this is a problem only visualizing with acroread, instead  evince shows the correct colors. Do you think this is a genuine problem with acroread, or it is due to the fact I did something wrong in my tex file?

Comment: It really seems to be an viewer problem, not related to TeX or beamer.